# Database primary key Guid as clustered index alternative

Tags: sql-server, index, azure-sql-database

I've red a couple of blogs/stackoverflow posts about not using a Guid as primary clustered key. Unfortunately we have at the moment and due to this we're experiencing performance degradation (with 900.000 rows in the database).

Our table looks like this:

```
| ID (PK)         | PARENTID (FK)    | CONTENT       | TYPE         | ROWVERSION |
| UNIQUEIDENIFIER | UNIQUEIDENTIFIER | NVARCHAR(MAX) | NVARCHAR(25) | rowversion |
```

In this table we're building up a tree (max 3 levels deep). The root has an empty ParentId, in other situation it's pointing to another Id (foreign key).

I want to refactor this table to the following, in order to prevent the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to be a primary key:

```
| ID     | PARENTID | TECHID           | CONTENT       | TYPE         | ROWVERSION |
| BIGINT | BIGINT   | UNIQUEIDENTIFIER | NVARCHAR(MAX) | NVARCHAR(25) | rowversion |
```

I'm keeping the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in the table because that's what we expose/communicate to the outside world.

The question I have specifically. Which column(s) should be handy for my primary key?

1. The TechId as (non clustered) primary key and a clustered index on ID.
2. The TechId as (non clustered) primary key and a clustered index on ID and ParentId.
3. The Id as clustered primary key and a non clustered key on the TechId.

Or any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your content really need to be NVARCHAR(MAX)? This immediately will cause an increase in IO, even for small values. (MAX values are stored off-page)

Comment: Also, how do you know it's the GUID that is causing the performance problems? Is that an assumption at this stage?

Comment: @George.Palacios We store the content in the NVARCHAR(MAX) as a JSON. We know almost for sure that the issue is in the GUID. Because the index of our is all the team fragmented (> 99%). Removing items take a long time (15 seconds), selecting a simpel item by UNIQUEIDENTIFIER takes a lot of time as well.

Comment: How do you know the fragmentation is causing the issue though? Do you have wait statistics tracked?

Comment: Having a GUID as the pirmary key would cause inserts to be slower due to page splitting.  It shouldn't cause SELECTs on the primary key to be a lot slower.  However, you are on the right track to getting better performance by using a BIGINT as the primary key, but we can't be sure that will solve the performance problem you're having without a lot more information.  Best course of action is to repro the problem in a non-production environment, implement fixes, and confirm it addresses the issues.  Performance issues could be due to blocking or other things.

Comment: The performance concerns with GUIDs and primary keys tend to come from when the primary key is ALSO the clustered key.  I've found GUIDs perform at acceptable levels if they're not the clustered key.  It's better if they're also NOT the primary key, but sometimes  you have to make compromises with design/developers/sadists.